# Traversals through Tree.. In order problem with memory access violation

Tags: c++, tree-traversal, inorder

So I wrote up this little peace of code as practice for myself...

But i am getting in travers_inorder function at line ***traverse_inorder(p->left)***  memory access violation and program crashes.
Why???
Any ideas?

UPDATE: I am using visual studio 2008 SP1 an visual C++ compiler

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

struct tree_node
{
tree_node *left;
tree_node *right;
int value;
};
void populate_rnd_tree(tree_node *root, int cnt);
void traverse_inorder(tree_node *p);

int main()
{
srand(time(NULL));
tree_node * nTmp = new tree_node;

populate_rnd_tree(nTmp, 10);

traverse_inorder(nTmp);

return 1;
}

void populate_rnd_tree(tree_node *root, int cnt)
{
tree_node *old = root, *left, *right;

left = new tree_node;
right = new tree_node;

int val = 0;
// exit condition
if (cnt == 0) return;

val = rand()%50;
old->value = val;
old->left = left;
old->right = right;

populate_rnd_tree(left, cnt-1);
populate_rnd_tree(right, cnt-1);

return;
}

void traverse_inorder(tree_node *p)
{ 
if (p != NULL)
{
    traverse_inorder(p->left);
    cout << p->value << endl;
    traverse_inorder(p->right);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess: looks like you never actually set your final child nodes to `NULL` in your tree generation procedure.  As such, your conditional to stop traversing is never hit, as `left` and `right` are just uninitialized pointers.  In `populate_rand_tree`, do the following:

```
if (cnt == 0) 
{
    old->left = NULL;
    old->right = NULL; 
    return;
}
```

Alternatively, since you are using C++...

```
struct tree_node
{
    tree_node() : left(NULL), right(NULL) { }

    tree_node *left;
    tree_node *right;
    int val;
}
```

Comment: in C++, either use `0` or `nullptr` (C++0x) to initialize pointers. `NULL` is a C-macro that may not be suitable (depending on its definition) because C++ has stronger typing.... If I recall correctly.

Comment: @Matthieu M.- you are correct, but with his includes (iostream and time.h) it is defined in this case.  I often forget that NULL is a C macro because I always define it myself in my c++ projects...